# How to append a character at the end of string?

Tags: ruby

I have a string `foo:`
I want to append a character at the end of a string `[`
So the final output should be `foo: [`

I tried the following code.

`puts 'foo: ' << '['` &
`puts 'foo: ' + '['`

But both are appending the character in a new line & giving me the following output.

`foo:
[`

However, I want to append the character in the same line & want the below output:

`foo: [`

Comment: `puts 'foo: ' + '['` is correct and does not insert a newline.  Please check again and provide the actual code, and don't forget that text in web pages can be line-wrapped.

Comment: I don't know why the other answer (`puts 'foo' + ' ['`) was accepted: it is missing the colon. This one directly follows the OP's question. Hrmph.

Comment: The `puts 'foo: ' + '['` should produce the correct result. I don't know how a wrong answer is marked ass verify.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code snippet provided does not reproduce the stated problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does what you are looking for `puts 'foo: ' + ' ['`

Comment: How does `puts 'foo' + ' ['` render `foo: [`? The OP's example includes a colon and your answer does not.

Comment: There is a missing colon. It should be `puts 'foo: ' + '['` which is same in the question itself.